# Branding and "personal info"

Tags: docusignapi

We are in the process of rebranding our emails from Docusign. While we're able to customize the logo and a couple other fields, is it possible to customize the email address and name (currently specified under the Personal Info administration menu). Ideally we'd like to modify this based on the BrandID we are passing in. Changing "Brand Name" and "Company Name" under the Branding > Info options didn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to accomplish this through the Resource Files.

Login to your developer sandbox and go to `Preferences` -> `Branding`.  Once there click the `Edit` button on an existing brand (or create one if none present) and then go to `Resources` on the following page.  Here you will see the Resource files for sending, signing, and emails.  You can think of these as "templates" and editing them will affect anyone who uses that Brand.  You'll see that you can edit things like the email from fields.

Answer (score 1):

The Sender's Name and Email Address for any Envelope will always correspond to the values associated with the DocuSign account (i.e., user/membership) that sent the Envelope.  For example, if an Envelope is created/sent using **Bob Smith**'s account (**bob.smith@example.com**) -- whether sent via the DocuSign web UI or via the DocuSign API -- the recipient will see that the Envelope came from **Bob Smith** (**bob.smith@example.com**).

Based on the scenario you've described, a potential work-around for you might be:

- Create multiple user accounts within DocuSign -- one for each possible Sender.
- Add logic in your code to determine which user account should be used as the "Sender" when an Envelope is created, based upon BrandId that's selected (or whatever other criteria you want).

For example:

- If the Envelope is created with Brand_A, specify Alan Adams as the sender of the Envelope (i.e., include Alan's credentials in the X-DocuSign-Authentication header of the 'Create Envelope' API request).  The recipient(s) will see that the Envelope came from Alan.
- If the Envelope is created with Brand_B, specify Bob Smith as the sender of the Envelope (i.e., include Alan's credentials in the X-DocuSign-Authentication header of the 'Create Envelope' API request).  The recipient(s) will see that the Envelope came from Bob.